# Check if user is a fan of some Facebook page, or has put it in his favorites

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In facebook connect, how can I check if a user is a fan of my facebook page? Is it possible to track?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181251/in-facebook-connect-how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-a-fan-of-my-facebook-page-is)

How can I check thought the FB Javascript API if the current user is a fan of some page (not my own app or page, but another specific page)?

I need to check this from within the page inserted into the FB's canvas IFRAME, throught the JS SDK...I need to check whether he has "subscribed" to that page, is a fan of it (clicked "I like it") and possibly if he has put it into his favorites.

Is this possible?

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181251/in-facebook-connect-how-can-i-check-if-a-user-is-a-fan-of-my-facebook-page-is-i It looks like the user needs to be connected with Facebook Connect for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the JS API:

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id : fbPageId }, function(response){
    if(response == true){
        alert('the user is a fan');
    }else{
        alert('the user is not an fan or we don't have permission to check')
    }
});
```

Cheers,
Jeremy

Comment: This is using the old rest api, which is going to get deprecated.